# Inserting a text in formula for google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to insert a formula in Google app script but facing errors even after multiple approaches.

```
var b7_range = b1_range.offset(0,9).getA1Notation();   // M43
var b8_range = b1_range.offset(0,14).getA1Notation();  // R43
var b9_range = b1_range.offset(0,23);                  //AA43

const Custom = "Custom";
var formula = "="+"IF("+"$"+b7_range+ "=="+Custom+","+Custom+","+"($"+b7_range+"*(1-"+b8_range+")))";
b9_range.setFormula(formula);
```

after execution I am getting in cell `AA43` as

```
=IF($M43==Custom,Custom,($M43*(1-R43)))
```

What I want is:

```
=IF($M43=="Custom","Custom",($M43*(1-R43)))
```

I even tried

```
"="+"IF("+"$"+b7_range+ "== Custom, Custom,"+"($"+b7_range+"*(1-"+b8_range+")))" 

//and 

"="+"IF("+"$"+b7_range+ "=="+"Custom"+","+"Custom"+","+"($"+b7_range+"*(1-"+b8_range+")))"
```

but not able to get the desired output, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the template literals as follows?

#### From:

```
var formula = "="+"IF("+"$"+b7_range+ "=="+Custom+","+Custom+","+"($"+b7_range+"*(1-"+b8_range+")))";
```

#### To:

```
var formula = `=IF($${b7_range}=="${Custom}","${Custom}",($${b7_range}*(1-${b8_range})))`;
```

- In this modification, when if `b1_range` is the cell "D43", the formula of `=IF($M43=="Custom","Custom",($M43*(1-R43)))` is put to the cell "AA43".

#### Reference:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.